# Adb command to cancel/hang up incoming call

Tags: android, adb

On the adb shell I run the command "adb -s
 shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:123456" to simulate a fake incoming call to my testing device. It works great. But I also want to simulate a missed call from the ADB shell, as I would by telnet with the command "gsm cancel +123456", for example. I cannot find anywhere how to do this... Is this even possible with ADB? If so, how?

P.S: the command "adb -s  shell input keyevent 6" is not an answer!

Comment: the -s flag has to be followed by the serial number of your device. this is only necessary when you have multiple devices. -s on its own will throw an error.

Comment: and you can obtain the serial number of your device using 'adb devices'

Answer (score 9):

to hang up use

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
```

or

```
adb shell input keyevent 6
```

(without "-s")

Comment: This does however also lock the screen. Is there a similar/different command which just ends the call, instead of locking screen as well?

Comment: @ledwinder96 I didn't experience the locking, so it might be down to the settings on your device. depending on your lock type, you could potentially follow this with an unlock, for example if you require a swipe unlock, try adb shell input keyevent 82